# Run Matlab Script in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, matlab

I have matlab script textcreator.m that create some result file output.txt.

And there is some `matlab.aplication()` reference that "translate" matlab function to c# and some of the code is hard to convert to c# and i decide just run the script i made.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 
matlab.Execute(@"cd d:\textcreator.m");
```

How to run matlab script textcreator.m when i click a button on my pc that have Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost got it, but instead of `matlab.Execute("cd d:\textcreator.m")`, you should `matlab.Execute("cd d:\")`, then `matlab.Execute("run textcreator.m")`. So your code should be:

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 
matlab.Execute("cd d:\");
matlab.Execute("run textcreator.m");
```

I have also dug out a simple MLApp wrapper I wrote quite some time ago. Thought it would be useful for you.

```
class MLWrapper
{
    private readonly MLApp.MLApp _mlapp;

    public MLWrapper(bool visible = false)
    {
        _mlapp = new MLApp.MLApp();

        if (visible)
            ShowConsole();
        else
            HideConsole();
    }

    ~MLWrapper()
    {
        Run("close all");
        _mlapp.Quit();
    }

    public void ShowConsole()
    {
        _mlapp.Visible = 1;
    }

    public void HideConsole()
    {
        _mlapp.Visible = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run a MATLAB command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Text output displayed in MATLAB console.</returns>
    public string Run(string cmd)
    {
        return _mlapp.Execute(cmd);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run a MATLAB script.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Text output displayed in MATLAB console.</returns>
    public string RunScript(string scriptName)
    {
        return Run($"run '{scriptName}'");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change MATLAB's current working folder to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    public void CD(string directory)
    {
        Run($"cd '{directory}'");
    }

    public object GetVariable(string varName)
    {
        _mlapp.GetWorkspaceData(varName, "base", out var data);
        return data;
    }

    public void SetVariable(string varName, object value)
    {
        _mlapp.PutWorkspaceData(varName, "base", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can handle with long path : Error using cd
Too many input arguments.

Comment: @sebachtian You have to wrap the path with single quotation marks if there is one or more space in the path. For example, `matlab.Execute("cd 'c:/folder with space';")`